# Doctrine 2 - How can I add a CHECK .. IN constraint

Tags: doctrine-orm

How can I add a CHECK .. IN constraint, like in the code below, in Doctrine 2?

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    colum_name VARCHAR(1) 
    CHECK (column_name IN ('A','B','C'))
);
```

-- *edit: I use annotations to define my entities*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not supported by the ORM itself. You can define custom DDL to be used for those columns through your metadata driver. For instance, in the `AnnotationDriver` you can use `/** @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(1) CHECK (column_name IN ('A','B','C'))") */` as defined in the [Annotations Reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column).
I would avoid it anyway and keep those checks on application level.

Comment: Is there any sample code available how to implement it for the MySQL driver?

Comment: @Ocramius Why would you avoid it and keep those checks on application level?

Comment: I strongly disagree with the "do it at the application level" , 12+ years of development has taught me something "someone will always write an other piece of code to touch the database"  , and they will forgot to reimplement all the check you've made.  At the opposite at the database level, if it's defined you're 100% sure it's respected.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_column for the new link

Comment: @allan.simon absolutely.  Unfortunately this opinion seems to be popular with Ocramius.  I recall another discussion a couple years ago that he had a very similar opinion on.  Your database is your source of truth, it should be validated for data integrity, first and foremost.  As you state, there are numerous ways for someone to insert crap data and cause downstream bugs and issues.

Comment: @JacobThomason exactly,  saying the database check is not needed because the application can check, is like saying the backend does not need to check because your frontend already does some checks.

Comment: Please suggest an edit after testing it carefully: `columnDefinition=""` support got a bit better over the years (not perfect, but still decent), and indeed, adding DB-side checks is OK, when supported in good RDBMS tech (PostgreSQL and similar).